# Finding duplicates from the same table having different ID using ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle8

I would like to find the duplicate casecitation_entry values that have different OBJECT_ID in CASE_CITATION table. Could you please advise the oracle SQL?

[image]

Comment: Well what have you tried?

Comment: Oracle 8? wow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem can be approached in multiple ways.  `EXISTS` is a typical one:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.CASE_CITATION = t.CASE_CITATION and t2.OBJECT_ID <> t.OBJECT_ID
             );
```

Comment: Also, if you want to find all the rows apart from the first one (so you can delete them for example) change `t2.OBJECT_ID <> t.OBJECT_ID` to `t2.OBJECT_ID < t.OBJECT_ID`